# How to match '**'?

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing a project in which the user types a math expression. I want to read every character on this comma separated list (, ), +, -, *, /, %, //, **.

I'm using regex module on Python. But I'm having trouble with ** and //.

Here's my code.

```py
import re

expression = input(">>> ")

r = re.findall(r"(\b\w*[\.]?\w+\b|[\(\)\+\*\-\/\%][\**][\\//])", expression)

print (r)
```

How do I correctly write the expression to find ** and // as well as * and /?

Comment: You should read the answers more carefully: the answer you’ve accepted doesn’t actually work properly and just happens to do the right thing “by accident”. The other answer explains *why* both your code and the other answer doesn’t work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you're not properly escaping the // and ** so the regex isn't looking for // and **

Try this: `(\b\w*[\.]?\w+\b|[\(\)\+\*\-\/\%][\*\*]?[\/\/]?)`

You can see an example of it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/J7pMEz/1)

Answer (score 2):

`[...]` is only for character classes: it matches single characters only, which `//` and `**` are not.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'//|\*\*|[()+\-*/%]')
r = pattern.findall(expression)
```

Comment: There’s no need to escape `-`. Conversely it should go either at the *beginning* or the *end* of a character class, not in the middle, to avoid accidentally denoting a range.

Comment: There _is_ a need to escape `-` if it isn’t at the beginning or end of the character class as it is in the OP’s code.

Comment: @barny So put it at the beginning or the end then. Escaping it in the middle works but I feel it’s error-prone. Better to always put it at either end.